# How to post a html formatted blog to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using a Nodejs server and a mysql database. I am trying to create a programming blog. My blog post table in the mysql database looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `user_id` int(11) NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `subTitle` varchar(255) NULL,
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `imageLocation` varchar(100) NULL,
 `body` text NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `tags` varchar(50) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
).
```

I am guessing I would have to store my individual blog posts as HTML so that the formatting is preserved? I am a bit confused about this process. Do I use something like TinyMCE to publish posts to my database? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing good.

The best way is to store it in a `TEXT` column, and yes your HTML formatting would be preserved.

There is no difference in how you're producing the `HTML` code, you just need to escape the `HTML` content and store it right in the database.

Comment: The idea behind css and frameworks like wordpress and co is to seperate design from text, so that you can change the design quickly or add a dark mode, without updateing your data

Comment: Is there any alternative to tinyMCE?

Comment: @nbk I see, and I like the idea you just mentioned. But, I think the question is more about the idea of storing `HTML` as a preserved string.

Comment: @jedu Yes for sure, there is a bunch of them. IMO, TinyMCE is one of the bests, but it's your call. Check [this one](https://alternativeto.net/software/tinymce/)